# Magento database hidden column

Tags: database, column

I'm having a problem with the catalog_eav_attribute table of magento database.
Some columns are hidden but if i click on each rows i can see them.
I've tried a lot of solution proposed in other posts like copying the table to another db and then restore it, delete the database and restore the backup.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Magento version: 2.1.7